# Configure AWS cli inside chef cookbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, aws-cli

I am working on setting up something with S3 and Chef, I have AWS CLI installed and working but I need to figure out how to specify the `access ID` and the `secret access key`. I know there are cookbooks out there for this but I have tried a few with no luck so I am not using anyone else's cookbooks for this project anymore.

Suggestions on how I can run `aws configure` and then output the correct value for each of the 4 things it asks?

Code in my script to set env variables:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key>

export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret_key>

export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<region>
```

Comment: Are you sourcing that script? https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it

Comment: You can run `echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` to verify that it worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html)? By setting these variables **before** you run your cli commands, you should not have to run the `aws configure` command.

> **Environment Variables**
>
> Environment variables override configuration and
>   credential files and can be useful for scripting or temporarily
>   setting a named profile as the default.
>   The AWS CLI supports the following environment variables.
>
> `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` – AWS access key.
>
> `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` – AWS secret key. Access and secret key
>   variables override credentials stored in credential and config files.
>
> `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` – Specify a session token if you are using temporary
>   security credentials.
>
> `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` – AWS region. This variable overrides the default
>   region of the in-use profile, if set.
>
> ....

Comment: Yes those are the settings I wanted to change, I was not aware they were env variables, thanks

Comment: I have the values for everything except `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` am I fine to go without it? I can't seem to find anything about this in the credentials I was provided.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have multifactor authentication enabled? You should be good then.

Comment: No 2FA enabled correct, it seems I am not so fine doing `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="value"` doesn't seem to be working and setting it correctly in my script.

Comment: I tried it without the `"` and the `export` as well with no luck

Comment: What OS/distro are you running on?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 currently

Comment: Can you post your code in the question?

Comment: It has been added

Comment: Are you setting your environment variables in the same script that is running the AWS Cli? Are you sure you are not setting them in a different shell?